# SearchCursor too many values to unpack

Tags: arcpy, cursor, dictionary

I'm trying to build a dictionary from a table view in ArcMap using SearchCursor. Here is the snippet of code I'm having issues with:

```
valueDi = dict([(key, val) for (key, val) in
             arcpy.da.SearchCursor
             (joinFc, [joinIdFld, joinValFld])])
```

This is the error I'm geting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "N:\Common\Script\Drivers\PrepCleanScapesUpdate.py", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I've checked the brackets and parentheses against a snippet of code used in an answer to [Using UpdateCursor for joined field in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177923)

Comment: the list within the searchcursor is a list not a dictionary so you cannot use the 2 iterators in looping through it

Comment: I changed the second (key, val) to row and still getting too many values to unpack. valueDi = dict([(key, val) for row in
                 arcpy.da.SearchCursor
                 (joinFc, [joinIdFld, joinValFld])])

Comment: The first half of the code presented seems irrelevant to the error message that you are asking about.  Do you still get the error when you `import arcpy` and then run only the code from `joinFc = "GarbSeq"
`?  If so, then that should be your code snippet.

Comment: Got rid of the first part. Thought working in Table View might have caused some issues.

Comment: I think you got rid of too much because now you are using variables for which we can no longer see values, and you have not imported ArcPy.  Perhaps review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure which field you want your dictionary key to be, but for the answer I am providing I made it the joinldFld, you can easy change it by switching the index.

```
valueDi = {x[0]: x[1] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(joinFc, [joinIdFld, joinValFld])}
```

I originally thought you cannot use two iterators on the searchcursor because the fields are stored in a tuple or list but this worked for me as well. if someone can explain why the below worked it would be very beneficial to this problem

```
valueDi = {k:v for k,v in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(joinFc, [joinIdFld, joinValFld])}
```

Comment: NP. which one worked out for you?

Comment: The first one {x[0]: x[1] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(joinFc, [joinIdFld, joinValFld])}