# Updating field values of footprint attribute table from an excel sheet

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, footprint

We have 60 - 70 footprints for which the attributes are to be updated for 25 columns. Some of the columns will have coded values (Eg: Country, Metadata standard, Language). I've slightly modified the code provided in this thread [Using UpdateCursor for joined field in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177923/using-updatecursor-for-joined-field-in-arcpy) (Second one - Code provided by Emil Brundage ). Since i don't know how to make the fields to be read in loop, for 25 fields i've used the same code. As an example i've only listed three fields.

Every column in the footprint is getting updated with the values from an excel sheet w.r.t "Name"column in both footprint & excel sheet. But "Language"column has not been updated and all i am getting is ""Create cursor has failed". "Language""column has coded values (English, Spanish, Portugese etc..). But the other columns with coded values are getting updated without any issues. Any suggestions on how to sort this out ?

```
import arcpy

footprint = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
footprintFld1 = "Title"
footprintFld2 = "Date"
footprintFld3 = "Language"
footprintIdFld = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

excel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
excelFld1 = "Title"
excelFld2 = "Date"
excelFld3 = "Language"
excelIdFld = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

valueDi = dict ([(key, val) for key, val in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (excel, [excelIdFld, excelFld1])])
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (footprint, [footprintFld1, footprintIdFld]) as cursor:
    for update, key in cursor:
        if not key in valueDi:
            continue
        row = (valueDi [key], key)
        cursor.updateRow(row)            

del cursor

valueDi = dict ([(key, val) for key, val in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (excel, [excelIdFld, excelFld2])])
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (footprint, [footprintFld2, footprintIdFld]) as cursor:
    for update, key in cursor:
        if not key in valueDi:
            continue
        row = (valueDi [key], key)
        cursor.updateRow(row)

del cursor

valueDi = dict ([(key, val) for key, val in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (excel, [excelIdFld, excelFld3])])
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (footprint, [footprintFld3, footprintIdFld]) as cursor:
    for update, key in cursor:
        if not key in valueDi:
            continue
        row = (valueDi [key], key)
        cursor.updateRow(row)

del cursor
... 
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 35, in <module>
RuntimeError: create cursor has failed
>>>
```

35th line in the code is // valueDi = dict ([(key, val) for key, val in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (excel, [excelIdFld, excelFld3])]) //. And, i am running this script as a tool from ArcToolbox.

Comment: Please remove the try/except statements from your [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) so that you and we can see the error messages that Python provides (including line number).

Comment: I've removed the try/except statements

Comment: Rather than struggle with domains, simply replace values in Excel table to codes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this looks "unusual":

```
    if not key in valueDi:
        continue
    row = (valueDi [key], key)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Perhaps try this instead:

```
    if key in valueDi:
        row = (valueDi [key], key)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Tried it. Getting the same error

Comment: File "<string>", line 35, in <module>, which means does it have to d anything with filename or field name in this line "// valueDi = dict ([(key, val) for key, val in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (excel, [excelIdFld, excelFld3])]) "

Comment: I don't see `//` in your code.